# Parasitic spikes on the primary side of a relay

Tags: relay, filter

I'm building a system that will measure current through a current clamp. To maximize accuracy, several rounds (100) are done around the clamp (see picture of early prototype).
The system is powered by a 220V / 6v transformer connected to sector (50Hz).

[image]

There may be a 0 to 25 Ohm resistor in the circuit (I will have several relay modules that will commute different resistors). The wire rounds around the clamp on the picture provides ~1 Ohm of resistance.

The system is commuted via [this](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/2-channel-New-2-channel-relay-module-relay-expansion-board-5V-low-level-triggered-2-way/32713335353.html) relay module. It contains an optocoupler, a free wheel diode and a transistor.
The relay module is controlled by a microcontroler.

[image]
The problem is that when commuting on or off the relay, I observe voltage spikes up to +/- 60 volts on the primary of relay module (basically VDD).

[image]

The microcontroler and the relay are powered from PC USB. I tried to power the relay with a bench power supply but the result is the same.

What can I do to filter this?

Thanks

Julien

Comment: A readable schematic could help

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Changed.

Comment: Where are you connecting the 'scope probe and ground?  Are the relay Vdd and GND the same as the processor Vdd and GND as implied by the circuit? If so, the optocoupler is not necessary. If not, then what is providing the relay power?

Comment: @Richard: Scope is connected beetween gnd and VDD. Yes they are the same for processor and relay. You're right about the optocoupler. But this circuit also has a strap (not drawn on the schematic) to disconnect power of relay from processor. As stated in the last paragraph of the question, I opened the connection (vdd processor - relay) and plug a bench power supply only for the relay but the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several unsuccessfull attemps of filtering VDD on the control side of the relay. I suspected that a 100 MHz oscillation could be relay bounces like when using a simple switch. I added a 200nF capacitor in parrallel of the relay on the controlled side and it did the trick.

[image]